# Sharing text to twitter

Tags: iphone

I know how to share a text viz twitter,i used [this code](http://iphoneapp-dev.blogspot.com/2011/07/how-to-send-text-to-twitter-account.html) to integrate my text to twitter,i had sucessfully done in xcode3.2,but now i use the xcode4.I got 60 errors when i put this code to my app.Error says

```
/Users/admin/Downloads/ELTouchBible/Classes/MGTwitterLibXMLParser.h:10:30: error: libxml/xmlreader.h: No such file or directory
/Users/admin/Downloads/ELTouchBible/Classes/MGTwitterLibXMLParser.m:50: error: 'XML_PARSE_NOBLANKS' undeclared (first use in this functio
```

There are lots of error like this.How to solve this errors?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It says that it cant find the xmlreader.h file? Is it still in your project?

Comment: @Rolf Koenders its not in my project.but how to add this to my project?examble link also have no xmlreader.h file,but it works great.

Comment: Did you add any header flags or search paths?

Comment: @RolfKoenders i add entire file from the exapmpkle project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use libxml in your Xcode 4 project, you need to do three things:

1) Add `libxml2.dylib` as a framework

2) Look for the build setting **Header Search Paths**, and add `/usr/include/libxml2`

3) `#include <libxml/parser.h>` (or whichever functions you need) in your source file(s).

To perform steps 1 and 2, you should select the root of your project in the left files pane. Frameworks can be added in on the **Summary** tab, and the build settings are on the **Build Settings** tab.

Answer (score 0):

Again its my Guess :-

**Check Whether all your frameworks are there or not in your project.If they are written in red color means they are not imported and you have to import it again.**

check this for your files also..